# Laravel 5.5 Geocoder

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, geocoding

I wanted to use [this package](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel) for geocoding in Laravel. I have added it to providers and published the config, but I am getting trouble setting it up to work.

```
    try {
        $location = Geocoder::geocode('68.145.37.34')->get();
        return $location;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
```

This returns empty object.

I have left the config file as is.

```
return [
    'cache-duration' => 9999999,
    'providers' => [
        Chain::class => [
            GoogleMaps::class => [
                'en-US',
                env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'),
            ],
            GeoPlugin::class  => [],
        ],
    ],
    'adapter'  => Client::class,
];
```

And added valid API key to `env`. Is there something I'm missing?

Geocoder is imported as `use Geocoder\Laravel\Facades\Geocoder;`

**EDIT**

In case someone gets to the same problem...this is how you'd get the country from it:

```
app('geocoder')->geocode('5.43.168.58')->get()->first()->getCountry()->getName();
```

Really complicated unnecessarily in my opinion, I requested a documentation change on official repo.

Comment: Have your tried one of the other IP aware Geocoding services? Like `FreeGeoIp::class`?

Comment: Well not really, but I wasn't searching for alternatives, I'm simply not sure how to make this work

Comment: Many thanks to you.
You save my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try using **dd()** in tinker?? I have been try it...and it work for me..

try this :

```
dd(app('geocoder')->geocode('68.145.37.34')->get());
```

response :

```
    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#764
  items: array:1 [
    0 => Geocoder\Model\Address {#753
      -coordinates: Geocoder\Model\Coordinates {#755
        -latitude: 51.0823
        -longitude: -113.9578
      }
      -bounds: null
      -streetNumber: null
      -streetName: null
      -subLocality: null
      -locality: "Calgary"
      -postalCode: null
      -adminLevels: Geocoder\Model\AdminLevelCollection {#767
        -adminLevels: array:1 [
          1 => Geocoder\Model\AdminLevel {#768
            -level: 1
            -name: "Alberta"
            -code: "AB"
          }
        ]
      }
      -country: Geocoder\Model\Country {#769
        -name: "Canada"
        -code: "CA"
      }
      -timezone: null
      -providedBy: "geo_plugin"
    }
  ]
}
```